# Failed to set beacon parameters error when creating a Captive portal

Tags: networking, 21.10, hostapd

I'm trying to create a captive portal on a ubuntu machine with the following network card: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485.

But I'm having a problem when I start the hostapd configuration, it gives the error "Failed to set beacon parameters" and the detailed log says "Beacon set Failed: -95 (Operation not supported)".

The hostapd configuration file looks like this

```
interface=wlp3s0
ssid=MyTest
channel=6
driver=nl80211
```

Does this error mean that my network card is incompatible?

When executing the command `iw list` it appears that the network card supports "AP" mode so I think it should not be a problem.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Thank you